# content versioning and csv import in liferay cms

Tags: java, liferay, survey

I am working on survey module .. I want to use Life ray for content management ..
The administrator Post set of questions and answers in the cms panel (preferably csv import).

The set of questionnaire needs to be version-ed and changes to the any item in the set needs to update the version of entire set.

when I request for particular version I should get the entire set of questionnaire of that version through web service..

Can liferay used as web service..? Does it meet my requirements..? and Does it has multimedia file upload support?

Answer (score 0):

Using Liferay solely for its CMS functionality seems like a bit of overkill in this case, certainly if you're not developing a portlet or portlets, but just using Liferay to store CMS data for a separate web application (or even standalone desktop app).

That being said, the Liferay CMS can be called via [webservices](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Liferay+Web+Services+Listing). As far as I can see a problem will be how you are going to represent your survey/questionnaire in the [Liferay CMS](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/building-a-site-with-liferay-s-w-2). As you don't really provide a lot information about how they are made up/structured I can't really elaborate on this a lot, but it would seem to me that you'd possibly have to split 1 survey up into multiple Liferay CMS articles (based on structures and templates). This would mean that you would have to write a custom service that encapsulates the versioning system you describe as a change to one article in Liferay doesn't propagate to other linked articles by default.

Liferay also has a 'media gallery' component which should be sufficient to support your media file upload requirement (it is also available via webservices).